# 1 array into 2 string arrays with malloc problems and pass by ref

Tags: c

HI I am working on something for one of my classes.. Im

trying to take in this array of strings, break it up into 2 arrays and return back to the caller.. I am new to C, so if you could help, be very helpful, thanks...
Right now I get a compile warning, and then a Segfault when I run it.

I've been trying many things such as changing the method signature by adding *'s and passing by &.. but it seems not to work..

I prolly am doing a bunch of stuff wrong... pls help.. what I want is to return 2 arrays back to main()  with 
pList[0] = "less"

and cList[0] = "ls"
and cList[1] = "-t" 
...from the function by passing in by reference..

heres my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void makeLists(char **args, char*** parentList, char*** childList, int *childEnd, int *parentEnd) {
int i;
int foundPipeAt = 0;
int total = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    total++;
    if (strcmp(args[i], "|") == 0) {
        foundPipeAt = i;
    }

}

*parentList = malloc((foundPipeAt-1) * sizeof(char*));
*childList = malloc((total-(foundPipeAt)) * sizeof(char*)); 

printf("foundPipe %d\n", foundPipeAt);
for (i = 0 ; i < foundPipeAt ; i++ ) {
    *parentList[i] = (char *) malloc( (strlen(args[i])+1) * sizeof(char));
    *parentList[i] = args[i];
    printf("Parent List: %s\n", *parentList[i]);
}

// Set values for Parent end    
*parentEnd = foundPipeAt-1;
*childEnd = total-foundPipeAt;


int k=0;
for (i = foundPipeAt+1 ; i < total ; i++ ) {
    *childList[k] = malloc((strlen(args[i])+1)  * sizeof(char));
    *childList[k] = args[i];
    // This prints  correctly...
    printf("Child List:  %s\n", *childList[k]);
    k++;
}
}



main() {
int i;
char *args[4]; 
args[0] = "ls";
args[1] = "-t";
args[2] = "|";
args[3] = "less";

char **pList;
char **cList;

int parentEnd, childEnd;
makeLists(args, &pList, &cList, &childEnd, &parentEnd);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message  `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]` is caused by a missing header. you need to add `stdlib.h` at the beginning of your code. After that, everything is fine.

btw, it is pass by value not by ref although the value itself is a pointer.

The second problem is `*parentList[i] = args[i];`,  you can use `strcpy(*parentList[i] , args[i]);`. Do this to `childList[i]` too.

btw, you don't need a triple pointer, a double one should do it.

Comment: that got rid of the warning, but i still get a seg fault

Comment: thanks so much so far, but it seems not to be passing ...
main() {
int i;
char *args[4]; 
args[0] = "ls";
args[1] = "-t";
args[2] = "|";
args[3] = "less";

char **pList;
char **cList;

int parentEnd, childEnd;
makeLists(args, pList, cList, &childEnd, &parentEnd);

   printf("Parent list Item 0 :  %s\n", pList[0]);
 
}

Comment: I  get a seg fault there in the main

Comment: if you check your `makeLists` function, parentList is always prefixed with a star `*` which suggest that you can just use double pointer and user `parentList` directly instead of `*parentList'. So what I saying is that you change `makeLists` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
count [1]  [2]  [3] [4]
index [0]  [1]  [2] [3]
arg   [ls] [-t] [|] [less]
```

foundPipeAt is the index of the pipe, but it's also the count of the parents.

```
// foundPipeAt - 1 gives you 1 less than you need
*parentList = malloc((foundPipeAt-1) * sizeof(char*));

// total - foundPipeAt gives you 1 more than you need
*childList = malloc((total-(foundPipeAt)) * sizeof(char*));

// i < foundPipeAt loops 1 past the amount you allocated
for (i = 0 ; i < foundPipeAt ; i++ )
```